# Trying to determine how to read input from console that could be over 10,000 characters in length

Tags: java, bufferedreader

I'm currently trying determine how to use bufferedreader to read from a console program. I know the correct syntax to read from the console and I know the program is working for smaller text. However, any text greater than 5118 characters will be truncated. The console itself will also not print out any text greater than 5118 characters. The goal is to create a java program that will read from the console independent of the size of data being read.

The following is the code I have created.

```
package countAnagrams;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.*;

public class TestClass {

public static int check_For_Missing_Characters(String a1, String b1){

int first_String_Length = a1.length();
int missing_Characters = 0;
for( int y = 0; y < first_String_Length; y++ ){
     final char character_To_Check_String = a1.charAt(y);
    if ( b1.chars().filter(ch -> ch == 
  character_To_Check_String).count() == 0 ){
        missing_Characters+=1;
    }
  }
 return missing_Characters;

}   
public static int check_For_Duplicate_Characters(String a1, String 
b1){
    int first_String_Length = a1.length();
    int duplicat_Characters = 0;
    String found_Characters = "";
    for( int y = 0; y < first_String_Length; y++ ){
        final char current_Character_To_Check = a1.charAt(y);
        long first_String_Count = b1.chars().filter(ch -> ch == 
                current_Character_To_Check).count();
        long second_String_Count = a1.chars().filter(ch -> ch == 
                current_Character_To_Check).count();
        long found_String_Count = found_Characters.chars().filter(ch -> ch == current_Character_To_Check).count();
        if ( first_String_Count > 0 && second_String_Count > 0 && found_String_Count == 0 ){
            duplicat_Characters+=Math.abs(first_String_Count - second_String_Count);
            found_Characters = found_Characters + 
current_Character_To_Check;
        }
    }
  return duplicat_Characters;
}
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception  {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

     BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        int test_Case_Count = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());  // 
Reading input from STDIN

        for(int x = 0; x < test_Case_Count; x++ ){
            int total_Count_Of_Diff_Chars = 0;
            StringBuilder  first_StringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            int first_String = '0';
            while(( first_String = br.read()) != -1 ) {
                 first_StringBuilder.append((char) first_String );
            }

            StringBuilder  second_StringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            String second_String = "";
            while((( second_String = br.readLine()) != null )){
                second_StringBuilder.append(second_String);
            }

            total_Count_Of_Diff_Chars = total_Count_Of_Diff_Chars +  
                     check_For_Missing_Characters(first_StringBuilder.toString(), 
                            second_StringBuilder.toString());
            total_Count_Of_Diff_Chars = total_Count_Of_Diff_Chars + 
                     check_For_Missing_Characters(second_StringBuilder.toString(), 
                            first_StringBuilder.toString());
            total_Count_Of_Diff_Chars = total_Count_Of_Diff_Chars + 
                     check_For_Duplicate_Characters(second_StringBuilder.toString(), 
                            first_StringBuilder.toString());
            System.out.println(total_Count_Of_Diff_Chars);
        }

           br.close();

        }

}
```

The above code will work for input that is less than 5118 characters. I would like to understand what is need to make it read beyond the 5118 limit. I'm not sure if the page, I using is causing the limit or there is something that I'm missing. Remember this is also written in java code.

Comment: Unrelated: look into using better names. Loop indexes go i, j, ... x implies float/double. Dont use count1, count2, count3 ... use names that say what the variable is about. Your code is very hard to read and understand, and the fact that you use so many nothing telling names is a big part of that.

Comment: How are you providing the input? Note that many applications such as IDE's may also have their own max buffer sizes. What's the point of the *two* `StringBuilder` instances?

Comment: `String copy2 = (char) firstSt1 + ""; firstSt.append(copy2);` would be more easily (and efficiently) written as `firstSt.append((char) firstSt1);`. But then, reading into a `char[]` would be more efficient than reading one char at a time.

Comment: I was not read all your code, but I have some coments
 - there is no limit in java for stdin buffer
 - your first inner loop 'while(( firstSt1 = br.read()) != -1 )' reads whole input. Second one will skip with empty result. 
 - main loop will read something only in first iteration.

Comment: What the result from ```int count = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine())``` , also I don't think you need the second argument ```50000``` on the BufferedReader constructor, so just ```new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in))```

Comment: Will the `new BufferedReader(..., int sz)` constructor fit your needs? You can specify a size for the buffer. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#BufferedReader-java.io.Reader-int-

Comment: Ok, I have updated the code. The issue I'm having is that the bufferedReader is only returning 5118 characters for the first string and not reading the remaining characters from the console. The total number of characters to read from the console is 19,997. The first string should be 9,998, so I'm missing 4,880. I'm using a website to try and practice coding, but I'm not sure if I'm having a problem with the site or if I'm having a problem with the code. bufferReader readline should read all the characters until it reaches end of line \n.

Comment: Yes, I tried to increase the buffer original. However, it still had same issue. My next step is to try the code in eclipse to see if I have the same problems. If it works in eclipse, then I think the issue is with the site. That would explain why no java solution has been provide for the practice code. Ok, has anyone tried using HackerEarth to practice coding ? Any recommendations for other sites that are java friendly ?

Comment: `while(( first_String = br.read()) != -1 )` consumes all the input, so nothing is left to read in the second `while`.

Comment: Ok, I understand that is how the while loop should work. However, can anyone explain why only 5118 characters are being counted verses 19,997 ?

Comment: Hello All, I was able to determine the issue and it was not with my code. The console on the site has a limit of the amount of characters is displays verses how many characters it being used when execute the code. It would have help if they explain that as well, because I kept thinking something was wrong with my code. I was able to get it work in my Eclipse IDE. It's hard to refresh you skills with some of this online tutorial sites, when their environment through errors not related to the code being tested.